# Velocity in View.

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, velocity, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on a custom `ViewController` similar to `UIPageController`.

I use a full subview in which I add a **PanGesture**. I want to change page if translation or velocity are high enough to change page. I was wondering if anyone established a list of standard value of velocity found when swiping on iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define kPanTranslationXForSwipe 15.0f

//...
- (void)handlePanGestureOnOverlayView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:pan.view];

    /********************************
     * Checking for swipe detection
     ********************************/
    if (abs(translation.x) > kPanTranslationXForSwipe) {
        // check swipe direction
        if (translation.x > 0) { //right
          //Do something for right swipe

          return;
        } else { //left
          //Do something for left swipe

          return;
        }
    }
    /********************************/

    // Do something for pan 
    //...
}
```

Comment: My question is not about the code but about standard value of your kPanTranslationXForSwipe which make sense for iPhone and iPad (resolution is different so Treshold are also different). Horizontal and Vertical swipe should also be different according to me

Comment: By the way, you just mentioned [pan translationInView:pan.view]; but [pan velocityInView:pan.view]; should also be used to make the best possible intercation